# Does the author write the word "off" instead of "of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

> Water enters a lake from overland flow **off** the surrounding land.

Source:https://books.google.com/books?id=Yin93qjdnAIC&pg=PA154&dq=%22overland+flow+off+the+surrounding+land.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAhLfh1ZDNAhUPkRQKHX9gAkwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22overland%20flow%20off%20the%20surrounding%20land.%22&f=true

Comment: *Off* sounds right to me.

Comment: what does it mean? Is it verb?

Comment: It's a preposition. The way I interpret that sentence is that there is water *on* the surrounding land, and some of it flows *off* into the lake. Just as water spilled on a table might flow off the table and onto the floor. (That overland flow likely wouldn't be the main source of water in the lake, but rainwater that falls on the land near the lake has to go somewhere - some will be absorbed into the ground, some will evaporate, and some runs off into the lake.)

Comment: Thank you nnnnnn. I consider "overland flow" as phrasal noun as it depicted in former page of the book and also here:http://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-90-481-3585-1_104

Comment: Yes, I consider *overland flow* a phrasal noun too, where *off* is a preposition that indicates where the overland flow came from.

Comment: Actually, you CAN write "of" in this sentence. Not, however, as a replacement of "off", but rather in addition to it. "_... overland flow off of the surrounding land_".

Comment: at the end of this page: http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/off_of.htm

Comment: Yes @Alireza but see also http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of  *Off of* is used by native speakers. Those who say it's redundant or bad English are countered by those who say it's an idiom and natural. I would probably not use it in formal contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Off* is a preposition:

> moving away and often down from

[Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/off)

*Flow* refers to something in motion, and many times takes the preposition *of* after it:

> the flow of the river
>   the flow of water
>   the flow of electricity
>   the flow of words

*Overland flow* is a [compound noun](https://www.google.com/search?q="compound+noun"). It refers to water that flows over land *down* towards a body of water.

It's  natural to think that *of* is the intended word in your sentence, giving:

> Water enters a lake from overland flow of the surrounding land

However, due to context and, in particular, the lack of the definite article before *overland flow*, we can correctly read *off* as a preposition.

> Water enters a lake from overland flow off the surrounding land

*overland flow* is running or flowing **off** the surrounding land into the lake.